# Windows 7 Professional N 64-bit drivers

Tags: windows-7

I have an **ASUS-N56DP** laptop. I installed **Win-7-professional-N-64-bit** on it. Unfortunately the drivers CD which was shipped together with the laptop *complains about the wrong version*. According to the error message shown the drivers on the CD are for Win7-starter/home/prof/ultimate-32/64 etc.pp.. In short the drivers do not support win7-N although win-7-N is nothing but "normal" windows without Internet Explorer and Media Player.

**Are there any workarounds to get the drivers installed?** I already tried to run the setup.exe with "Compatibility mode for win-7" enabled, but it didn't work.

Comment: If you have 64-bit drivers it will for any version of 64-bit Windows 7  The error indicates you don't have 64-bit drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Ramhound is correct. you don't have the correct drivers. I use Win7-N-64 bit as my media server and had no problems with it. Go online and download a fresh copy of the 64-bit drivers from the ASUS website.

Comment: I have tried to install the 64-bit drivers from the according Asus support page. It didnt work. Then i started the Asus-auto-detection-tool from the website. The tool did magic and it did work. Looked like it also looked for other dependencies like .NET Framework 4.5.